# Folium displaying blank map

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I'm having issues with displaying a folium map. It just shows a blank map. Same for the documentation:
[Folium documentation page](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html)

[image: blank map]

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. The same happens when I open it in explorer, firefox, or any other browser.I've asked around, and a lot of other people also see a blank map.

Comment: From your screenshots, it seems the underlying problem is `Failed to load resource: NET::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` when attempting to load the `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css` files. Use your browser's [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to pinpoint the problem. I suspect it might be a firewall/proxy issue.

Comment: It is indeed leaflet.js that fails:

Using network monitor: Headers:

Request URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Referer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js can't be reached.
Leaflet docs suggest using https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js